# Keyboard binding: deleteWordForward not working

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I have the following code in my `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file:

```
{
    "~f"        = "moveWordForward:";               /* M-f          Move forward word */
    "~b"        = "moveWordBackward:";              /* M-b          Move backward word */
    "~d"        = "deleteWordForward:";             /* M-d          Delete word forward */
}
```

The first two, M-f and M-b works as intended to move forward/backward one word, but the M-d button doesn't (it doesn't do anything). Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue? Thanks!